# play the recorded file whose path is attached in flash media srver

Tags: netstream, flash-media-server

in adobe flash media server 4.0, how can I programmatically attached the path to the recorded file which is played by a client. e.g.,

in client side,

> mynetStream.play
>   ("myrecordedfile.flv")

how to redirect the playing to the file under e.g., c:\my_dynamic_file_path.

note that, the file path is changable based on the client's login name.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the below is a good solution or not,

in client side:

```
mynetStream.play
("myrecordedfile.flv");

netconn.call ("playStream", null, "myrecordedfile.flv", username);
```

in flash media server side,

```
Client.prototype.playStream = function
(streamname, username) {

   var s = Stream.get (streamname);   
var file = username + "\" +
streamname;    s.play (file, 0, -1); 
}
```